# How to show help text if no arguments are passed

Tags: linux, bash

I've been using getopts recently and I've set everything up. I've got a problem though. I want it to work so that if someone doesn't enter an argument on the command line, they get the help text, e.g.:

```
$ ./script
$ help: xyz - argument must be used.
```

Here's what I have at the moment.

```
#!/bin/bash

function helptext {
    # ...
}

function mitlicense {
    # ...
}


while getopts "hl" opt; do
  case $opt in
    h) helptext >&2
      exit 1
    ;;
    l) mitlicense >&2
      exit 0
    ;;
    \?) echo "Invalid option: -$OPTARG" >&2
      exit 1
    ;;
    :) echo "Option -$OPTARG requires an argument." >&2
      exit 1
    ;;
    *) helptext >&2
      exit 1
    ;;
  esac
done
```

Answer (score 9):

Validate user input using an if test such as below.

The `-z` option of `test` returns true if the length of the string which follows -z is zero.

```
 if [ -z "$1" ]
 then
  helptext
  exit 1
 fi
```

Comment: It's an edge case, but worth mentioning: your conditional also evaluates to true if `$1` _was_  passed, but as the _empty string_; e.g., `./script ''` and `./script '' foo` would still show the help text.

Answer (score 7):

Try using this in your script :

```
#!/bin/bash

[[ $@ ]] || { helptext; exit 1; }

# --- the rest of the script ---
```

The line of code is the boolean shortened version of

```
if [[ $@ ]]; then
    true
else
    helptext
    exit 1
fi
```

`$@` is all the arguments of the script

```
[[ $var ]]
```

is a shorthand for

```
[[ -n $var ]]
```

See http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashGuide/TestsAndConditionals

Answer (score 5):

[Gilles Quenot's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/users/465183/gilles-quenot) works great and is very concise; if you're looking for solutions that *express the intent more explicitly*, you can try these, which are based on the *count* of parameters, `$#`:

```
[[ $# -gt 0 ]] || { helptext; exit 1; }
```

Alternative, using arithmetic expressions:

```
(( $# > 0 )) ||  { helptext; exit 1; }
```

Finally, shorthand that relies on 0 evaluating to false, and any non-zero number to true:

```
(( $# )) || { helptext; exit 1; }
```

[William Pursell](https://stackoverflow.com/users/140750/william-pursell) offers another variant, which is both descriptive and POSIX-compliant:

```
test $# -gt 0 || { helptext; exit 1; }
```

<sup>`test` / `[ ... ]` is a POSIX utility/built-in, whereas the similar `[[ ... ]]` conditional is `bash`-specific (as is `(( ... ))`).

Generally, however, `bash`'s `[[ ... ]]` offers more features and has fewer surprises than `test` / `[...]`.</sup>